# How to safely rid a Macbook Pro's power port of chocolate?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

There was a chocolate coin from Christmas at the bottom of my laptop bag which managed to get shoved into the power port and conform to the space and fill it completely. I managed to scrape most of it away with tweezers but I'm afraid attempting to charge it will most definitely cause the residue to melt and harm the computer. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a magsafe port us a cotton swab or soft bristle tooth brush. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203207.

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49774/how-can-i-clean-a-magsafe-power-port-on-my-macbook-air](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49774/how-can-i-clean-a-magsafe-power-port-on-my-macbook-air) that has more answers.